# LINQ Case When Query

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, oracle

I have an SQL query like below in Oracle SQL syntax and I want it in LINQ equal.

```sql
Select Case When tbl.Id=1 then 1 else NULL End as col1,
Case When tbl.Id=2 then 2 else NULL End as col2,
Case When tbl.Id=3 then 3 else NULL End as col3
From Table1 tbl
```

Comment: You'd rather have tried something by the way, mister.

Answer (score 2):

You would use the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) in the `Select`:

```
var result = 
    table1.Select(x => new
                       {
                           col1 = x.Id == 1 ? (int?)1 : null,
                           col3 = x.Id == 2 ? (int?)2 : null,
                           col3 = x.Id == 3 ? (int?)3 : null
                       });
```

Comment: You forgot `(int?)`. :p

Comment: @AgentFire: Yeah, saw it in your answer. Fixed now :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var items = from item in Table1
            select new
            {
                 col1 = item.Id == 1 ? (int?)1 : null,
                 col3 = item.Id == 2 ? (int?)2 : null,
                 col3 = item.Id == 3 ? (int?)3 : null)
            };
```

Comment: @ehsan indeed and I've fixed that.