# How to order by value constructed with SQL "when" clause using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

This is the example and don't tell me to normalize. In many cases, this is normalized already

here is sample query

```
select lastname,firstname,gradelevel,major
    case gradelevel
    when 'Freshmen' then 1
    when 'Sophmore' then 2
    when 'Junior' then 3
    when 'Senior' then 4
    else 6
    end as gradelevelrank
    from student
order by gradelevelrank
```

How do I in linq?

Comment: Indeed this was asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781323/linq-case-when-query, but more specific answer already provided... so post simply deserves downvotes dues to lack of research shown, but probably not duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this...

```
var list = (from s in student
select new 
{
   lastname,
   firstname,
   gradelevel,
   major,
   gradeLevelRank =
   (
       gradelevel == "Freshmen" ? 1 : 
       gradelevel == "Sophmore" ? 2 :
       gradelevel == "Junior" ? 3 :
       gradelevel == "Senior" ? 4 : 6
   )
})
.OrderBy(gl => gl.gradeLevelRank)
.ToList();
```

Comment: Basic search https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+linq+when seem to agree with that solution...